Rancher Cluster creation stuck by waiting for cluster agent to connect
I am trying to setting up a Rancher Cluster with the docker install option.
Rancher version: 2.8.3
Server version: RedHat 8.9
After setting up podman on a server, I then started the rancher/rancher container.
A new cluster was then created with the default settings.
If a node is then added with the registration command, the node appears in the dashboard, but remains stuck at waiting for cluster agent to register.
In the logs of the rancher-system-agent on the node to be registered, it always appears that the secret is too old.
Cluster Provisioning Log
[INFO ] waiting for at least one control plane, etcd, and worker node to be registered
[INFO ] configuring bootstrap node(s) custom-8b637c9cd841: waiting for bootstrap etcd to be available
[INFO ] configuring bootstrap node(s) custom-8b637c9cd841: waiting for agent to check in and apply initial plan
[INFO ] configuring bootstrap node(s) custom-8b637c9cd841: waiting for probes: calico, etcd, kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, kubelet
[INFO ] configuring bootstrap node(s) custom-8b637c9cd841: waiting for probes: calico, kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler
[INFO ] configuring bootstrap node(s) custom-8b637c9cd841: waiting for probes: calico
[INFO ] configuring bootstrap node(s) custom-8b637c9cd841: waiting for cluster agent to connect

Rancher-System-Agent Log
rancher-system-agent[13135]: time="2024-04-30T14:27:40+02:00" level=info msg="[Applyinator] Running command: sh [-c rke2 etcd-snapshot list --etcd-s3=false 2>/dev/null]"
rancher-system-agent[13135]: time="2024-04-30T14:27:40+02:00" level=info msg="[12cb26ca54456920e77a29191a815c3d6fed7af28c7a8c072a4d5c214607e6fe_0:stdout]: Name Location Size Created"
rancher-system-agent[13135]: time="2024-04-30T14:27:40+02:00" level=info msg="[Applyinator] Command sh [-c rke2 etcd-snapshot list --etcd-s3=false 2>/dev/null] finished with err: <nil> and exit code: 0"
rancher-system-agent[13135]: time="2024-04-30T14:27:40+02:00" level=info msg="[K8s] updated plan secret fleet-default/custom-8b637c9cd841-machine-plan with feedback"
rancher-system-agent[13135]: time="2024-04-30T14:27:45+02:00" level=error msg="[K8s] received secret to process that was older than the last secret operated on. (14820 vs 18024)"
rancher-system-agent[13135]: time="2024-04-30T14:27:45+02:00" level=error msg="error syncing 'fleet-default/custom-8b637c9cd841-machine-plan': handler secret-watch: secret received was too old, requeuing"
rancher-system-agent[13135]: W0430 14:29:05.831181   13135 reflector.go:456] pkg/mod/github.com/rancher/client-go@v1.27.4-rancher1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: an error on the server ("unable to decode an event from the watch stream: stream error: stream ID 35; INTERNAL_ERROR; received from peer") has prevented the request from succeeding

Could it be that the error is caused by the problem with secret?
